# ASP .NET Session serialization cost!

Tags: asp.net, serialization, session-state

How can we measure the serialization overhead of custom classes in ASP .NET session when using an out of process session state provider - in this case Velocity distributed cache.

During load testing we see a lot of CPU consumption happening on the web servers, I was interested in getting some metrics related to the serialization aspect among other things before looking at optimizing the kind of objects we are stuffing in session.

Any help, pointers?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your application?

Comment: Your load testing tools should provide this type of information.  What are you using to do it?  Also, don't abuse session by storing a bunch of objects in it.  That just doesn't scale.

Comment: Profiling will show what's happening inside my application. Session serialization is an infra task which happens before the application code executes and hence would be difficult to see in the profiler I guess.

Comment: Load testing tool is load runner, it's shows all statistics related to request/response times, but not sure it will give me serialization metrics.

Comment: Profiling will show everything your process does, including non-user-code.